# Error in converting SQL query to mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a TSQL query which i used to create views in my sql server.
I have a similar MySQL environment where i wanted to create same set of views.
I converted Mssql query to mysql query with SQLLines online converter, since i am not so familiar with syntax and functions in mysql.
But the converted Mysql query is failing at the variable declaration itself.

**MSSQL query**

```
    USE DB
GO
DECLARE @qos varchar(255), @pos int, @r_table varchar(255), @view varchar(255), @cview varchar(2048)

DECLARE qos_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT qos,r_table FROM S_QOS_DATA
ORDER BY 2

OPEN qos_cursor

-- Perform the first fetch.
FETCH NEXT FROM qos_cursor INTO @qos, @r_table 

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

                -- Check QOS name for '-' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX('-',@qos, 1);
                IF @pos != 0
                BEGIN
                                SELECT @qos = STUFF(@qos, @pos, 1, '_');
                END

                -- Check QOS name for '/' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX('/',@qos, 1);
                IF @pos != 0
                BEGIN
                                SELECT @qos = STUFF(@qos, @pos, 1, '_');
                END

                -- Check QOS name for '(' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX('(',@qos, 1);
                IF @pos != 0
                BEGIN
                                SELECT @qos = STUFF(@qos, @pos, 1, '_');
                END

                -- Check QOS name for ')' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX(')',@qos, 1);
                IF @pos != 0
                BEGIN
                                SELECT @qos = STUFF(@qos, @pos, 1, '_');
                END

                -- Create view
                SET @view = 'V_'+@qos
                SET @cview = 'CREATE VIEW '+@view+' AS '+
                                'SELECT Q.source,Q.target,Q.origin,Q.robot,Q.probe,D.sampletime,D.samplevalue,D.samplestdev,D.samplerate,D.tz_offset '+
                                'FROM S_QOS_DATA Q JOIN '+@r_table+' D ON Q.table_id=D.table_id';

                BEGIN TRY
                                exec ('DROP VIEW '+@view)
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                                -- Suppress Error message for Views that don't exist
                END CATCH
                BEGIN TRY
                                -- Create the View, Catch tables that don't have samplestdev & samplerate fields
                                exec (@cview);
                                PRINT 'Created View: ' + @view
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                                SET @cview = 'CREATE VIEW '+@view+' AS '+
                                'SELECT Q.source,Q.target,Q.origin,Q.robot,Q.probe,D.sampletime,D.samplevalue,D.tz_offset '+
                                'FROM S_QOS_DATA Q JOIN '+@r_table+' D ON Q.table_id=D.table_id';
                                exec (@cview);
                                PRINT 'Created View: ' + @view
                END CATCH

                -- PRINT 'qos: ' + @qos + ' ' +  @r_table+' '+@view
                -- PRINT @cview
                -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
                FETCH NEXT FROM qos_cursor INTO @qos, @r_table

END

CLOSE qos_cursor
DEALLOCATE qos_cursor
GO
```

**MySQL Query:**

```
use DB;
DECLARE v_qos varchar(255); DECLARE v_pos int; DECLARE v_r_table varchar(255); DECLARE v_view varchar(255); DECLARE v_cview varchar(2048)

DECLARE qos_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT qos,r_table FROM S_QOS_DATA
ORDER BY 2

OPEN qos_cursor

-- Perform the first fetch.
FETCH NEXT FROM qos_cursor INTO v_qos, v_r_table 

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
WHILE NOT_FOUND = 0
DO

                -- Check QOS name for '-' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SET v_pos = CHARINDEX('-',v_qos, 1);
                IF v_pos != 0
                THEN
                                SET v_qos = INSERT(v_qos, v_pos, 1, '_');
                END IF;

                -- Check QOS name for '/' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SET v_pos = CHARINDEX('/',v_qos, 1);
                IF v_pos != 0
                THEN
                                SET v_qos = INSERT(v_qos, v_pos, 1, '_');
                END IF;

                -- Check QOS name for '(' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SET v_pos = CHARINDEX('(',v_qos, 1);
                IF v_pos != 0
                THEN
                                SET v_qos = INSERT(v_qos, v_pos, 1, '_');
                END IF;

                -- Check QOS name for ')' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SET v_pos = CHARINDEX(')',v_qos, 1);
                IF v_pos != 0
                THEN
                                SET v_qos = INSERT(v_qos, v_pos, 1, '_');
                END IF;

                -- Create view
                SET v_view = CONCAT('V_',v_qos)
                SET v_cview = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW ',v_view,' AS ',
                                'SELECT Q.source,Q.target,Q.origin,Q.robot,Q.probe,D.sampletime,D.samplevalue,D.samplestdev,D.samplerate,D.tz_offset ',
                                'FROM S_QOS_DATA Q JOIN ',v_r_table,' D ON Q.table_id=D.table_id');

                BEGIN TRY
                                set @stmt_str =  CONCAT('DROP VIEW ',v_view);
                                prepare stmt from @stmt_str;
                                execute stmt;
                                deallocate prepare stmt;
                END; TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                                -- Suppress Error message for Views that don't exist
                END; CATCH
                BEGIN TRY
                                -- Create the View, Catch tables that don't have samplestdev & samplerate fields
                                set @stmt_str =  v_cview;
                                prepare stmt from @stmt_str;
                                execute stmt;
                                deallocate prepare stmt;
                                /* PRINT CONCAT('Created View: ' , v_view) */
                END; TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                                SET v_cview = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW ',v_view,' AS ',
                                'SELECT Q.source,Q.target,Q.origin,Q.robot,Q.probe,D.sampletime,D.samplevalue,D.tz_offset ',
                                'FROM S_QOS_DATA Q JOIN ',v_r_table,' D ON Q.table_id=D.table_id');
                                set @stmt_str =  v_cview;
                                prepare stmt from @stmt_str;
                                execute stmt;
                                deallocate prepare stmt;
                                /* PRINT CONCAT('Created View: ' , v_view) */
                END; CATCH

                -- PRINT 'qos: ' + @qos + ' ' +  @r_table+' '+@view
                -- PRINT @cview
                -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
                FETCH NEXT FROM qos_cursor INTO v_qos, v_r_table

END WHILE

CLOSE qos_cursor
```

Looks like the online converter has replaced the functions appropriate for MySQL but when i execute the mysql query in my MySQL 5.7.20 i am getting

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE v_qos varchar(255); DECLARE v_pos int; DECLARE v_r_table varchar(255); D' at line 1

I tried declaring varibales like declare@, select @ both gives me error in MySQL.

I would love to explore myself,but timeline is short , so thought of seeking expert advice in community.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should update your code so that it doesn't have obvious syntax errors like that. That way others can figure out what the real problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semi colon `;` on the very last `DECLARE` statement...

You also need a semi colon `;` after `ORDER 2`...

and a semi colon `;` after `OPEN qos_cursor`...

Comment: semi colon is not the issue Jane.. because the first thing that i tried was semicolons u told. The problem is in declaring the variables..to conform that i just declared a single variable in mysql client  and got the same error

Comment: mysql> DECLARE v_qos varchar(255);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE v_qos varchar(255)' at line 1

Comment: i think error handling part(begin try) in mysql query is completely wrong.

Comment: Look, no one can help you until you fix all the obvious syntax errors in your statement.  There are several semi colons you missed, and your script won't work until you fix them.  I can't help you troubleshoot if your sample code is still filled with syntax errors.

Comment: Hi Jane.. I have written the mysql query and posted it here                                                  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184244/create-multiple-views-with-a-mysql-stored-procedure