# create multiple views with a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I wanted to build around 900 views(1 view for 1 table and based on 2 conditions) and i have all the table names in a table in mysql environment. I have created a stored proc . For test purpose i used limit 1.

I get below error when i call the sp. 
Actually I re-wrote a mssql sp, did i miss anything here. please help

> CALL `ca_uim`.`sp_viewcreation_ontime`()  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1    0.000 sec

```
    USE `ca_uim`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `sp_viewcreation_ontime`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `ca_uim`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_viewcreation_ontime`()
BEGIN
DECLARE qos varchar(255); 
DECLARE pos int; 
DECLARE r_table varchar(255); 
DECLARE view varchar(255); 
DECLARE cview varchar(2048);
DECLARE done int default 0;

DECLARE qos_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT qos,r_table FROM S_QOS_DATA ORDER BY 2 limit 1;
DECLARE continue handler for not found set done = 1;

OPEN qos_cursor;

-- Perform the first fetch.
FETCH qos_cursor INTO qos, r_table;

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
WHILE not done
DO

                -- Check QOS name for '-' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SET pos = LOCATE('-',qos, 1);
                IF pos != 0
                THEN
                                SET qos = INSERT(qos, pos, 1, '_');
                END IF;

                -- Check QOS name for '/' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SET pos = LOCATE('/',qos, 1);
                IF pos != 0
                THEN
                                SET qos = INSERT(qos, pos, 1, '_');
                END IF;

                -- Check QOS name for '(' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SET pos = LOCATE('(',qos, 1);
                IF pos != 0
                THEN
                                SET qos = INSERT(qos, pos, 1, '_');
                END IF;

                -- Check QOS name for ')' character & replace with '_' if exist
                SET pos = LOCATE(')',qos, 1);
                IF pos != 0
                THEN
                                SET qos = INSERT(qos, pos, 1, '_');
                END IF;

                -- Create view
                SET view = CONCAT('V_',qos);
                SET cview = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW ',view,' AS ',
                                'SELECT Q.source,Q.target,Q.origin,Q.robot,Q.probe,D.sampletime,D.samplevalue,D.samplestdev,D.samplerate,D.tz_offset ',
                                'FROM S_QOS_DATA Q JOIN ',r_table,' D ON Q.table_id=D.table_id');

                BEGIN
                                -- Suppress Error message for Views that don't exist
                                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1051
                                set @stmt_str =  CONCAT('DROP VIEW ',view);
                                prepare stmt from @stmt_str;
                                execute stmt;
                                deallocate prepare stmt;
                END;

                BEGIN
                                -- Create the View, Catch tables that don't have samplestdev & samplerate fields
                                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1054
                                set @stmt_str =  cview;
                                prepare stmt from @stmt_str;
                                execute stmt;
                                deallocate prepare stmt;
                                /* PRINT CONCAT('Created View: ' , view) */
                END;
                BEGIN
                                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1054
                                SET cview = CONCAT('CREATE VIEW ',view,' AS ',
                                'SELECT Q.source,Q.target,Q.origin,Q.robot,Q.probe,D.sampletime,D.samplevalue,D.tz_offset ',
                                'FROM S_QOS_DATA Q JOIN ',r_table,' D ON Q.table_id=D.table_id');
                                set @stmt_str =  cview;
                                prepare stmt from @stmt_str;
                                execute stmt;
                                deallocate prepare stmt;
                                /* PRINT CONCAT('Created View: ' , view) */
                END;

                -- PRINT 'qos: ' + @qos + ' ' +  @r_table+' '+@view
                -- PRINT @cview
                -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
                FETCH qos_cursor INTO qos, r_table;

END WHILE;

CLOSE qos_cursor;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks

Comment: *"I wanted to build around 900 views(1 view for 1 table and based on 2 conditions)"* Why what is the reason behide this? MySQL does not Materialize Views for faster access..

Comment: This just sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  It is the requirement given to me .. exposed views will be used by the dev team for reporting purposes

Comment: @Strawberry : The idea of creating view in mysql is bad or the way i am trying to achieve it looks bad?

Comment: Um, both, I'm afraid; one being a consequence of the other

Comment: *" It is the requirement given to me .. exposed views will be used by the dev team for reporting purposes"* did they think this over.. @Strawberry is not afraid for nothing and strawberry does not get scared easy. So if a table has 10 columns and you want a view based on 2 conditions you are going to make 20 views from one table imagine if you have 100 of those you have 2000 views and which view is the correct one to query?.. And what if the dev team need to use 3 conditions for reporting or 4 or 5, they are just lazy and not willing to type and didn't overthinked  this.

Comment: ... i think they are better off when you/they program a SQL generator function which generates a SQL query based on the data they need and which conditions, instead off generating all those views.. And then executes it.